# How are floating-point pixel values converted to integer values?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

How does image library (such as PIL, OpenCV, etc) convert floating-point values to integer pixel values?

For example

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Creates a random image and saves in a file
def get_random_img(m=0, s=1, fname='temp.png'):

    im =  m + s * np.random.randn(60, 60, 3) # For eg. min: -3.8947058634971179, max: 3.6822041760496904

    print(im[0, 0]) # for eg. array([ 0.36234732, 0.96987366, 0.08343])

    imp = Image.fromarray(im, 'RGB') #                         (*)

    print(np.array(imp)[0, 0]) # [140 , 74, 217] 

    imp.save(fname) 

    return im, imp
```

For the above method, an example is provided in the comment (which is randomly produced). My question is: **how** does `(*)` convert `ndarray` (which can range from - infinity to plus infinity) to pixel values between 0 and 255?

I tried to investigate the `Pil.Image.fromarray` method and eventually ended by at line #798 `d.decode(data)` within `Pil.Image.Image().frombytes` method. I could find the implementation of `decode` method, thus unable to know what computation goes behind the conversion.

My initial thought was that maybe the method use **minimum** (to 0) and **maximum** (to 255) value from the array and then map all the other values accordingly between 0 and 255. But upon investigations, I found out that's not what is happening. Moreover, how does it handle when the values of the array range between 0 and 1 or any other range of values?

Answer (score 3):

Some libraries assume that floating-point pixel values are between 0 and 1, and will linearly map that range to 0 and 255 when casting to 8-bit unsigned integer. Some others will find the minimum and maximum values and map those to 0 and 255. You should always explicitly do this conversion if you want to be sure of what happened to your data.

In general, a pixel does not need to be 8-bit unsigned integer. A pixel can have any numerical type. Usually a pixel intensity represents an amount of light, or a density of some sort, but this is not always the case. Any physical quantity can be sampled in 2 or more dimensions. The range of meaningful values thus depends on what is imaged. Negative values are often also meaningful.

Many cameras have 8-bit precision when converting light intensity to a digital number. Likewise, displays typically have an 8-bit intensity range. This is the reason many image file formats store only 8-bit unsigned integer data. However, some cameras have 12 bits or more, and some processes derive pixel data with a higher precision that one does not want to quantize. Therefore formats such as TIFF and ICS will allow you to save images in just about any numeric format you can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is a bit clear now.  You say that I should have my own convention to convert the image representing intensity with 8bit (or any size) value to float and vice-versa- sounds good. In view of the CNN generative network, the output is unbounded unless we use `sigmoid` or `tanh` to limit. Which one is a better idea b/w the two? Also while feeding an image to the network you normalize the data- should we denormalize during inference and when? After using `sigmoid` or `tanh` and then again clip or no need to denormalize.

Comment: @zeal: I don't have any experience with generative networks, but I don't think there's a huge difference between a sigmoid and `tanh`. They both clip the data but do it in a smooth way to allow differentiation for back projection. I guess you want to denormalize the output of your generative network after inference, to bring it into the 0-255 range suitable for display. If the output passes through a sigmoid or similar function, a simple linear mapping should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it has done nothing anywhere near as clever as you hoped! It has merely interpreted the first byte of the first float as a `uint8`, then the second byte as another `uint8`...

```
from random import random, seed
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate repeatable random data, so other folks get the same results
np.random.seed(42)

# Make a single RGB pixel
im =  np.random.randn(1, 1, 3)

# Print the floating point values - not that we are interested in them
print(im)                                                                                 
# OUTPUT: [[[ 0.49671415 -0.1382643   0.64768854]]]

# Save that pixel to a file so we can dump it
im.tofile('array.bin')

# Now make a PIL Image from it and print the uint8 RGB values
imp = Image.fromarray(im, 'RGB')
print(imp.getpixel((0,0)))                                                                
# OUTPUT: (124, 48, 169)
```

So, PIL has interpreted our data as RGB=124/48/169

Now look at the hex we dumped. It is 24 bytes long, i.e. 3 float64 (8-byte) values, one for red, one for green and one for blue for the 1 pixel in our image:

```
xxd array.bin
```

**Output**

```
00000000: 7c30 a928 2aca df3f 2a05 de05 a5b2 c1bf  |0.(*..?*.......
00000010: 685e 2450 ddb9 e43f                      h^$P...?
```

And the first byte (`7c`) has become 124, the second byte (`30`) has become 48 and the third byte (`a9`) has become 169.

**TLDR;** PIL has merely taken the first byte of the first float as the Red `uint8` channel of the first pixel, then the second byte of the first float as the Green `uint8` channel of the first pixel and the third byte of the first float as the Blue `uint8`  channel of the first pixel.